# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i > \ln(n+1)$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction

**Problem**

Prove $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac1i > \ln(n+1)$$

**Caveat**

While I'm familiar with the integral approach, this problems shows up in my textbook *before* integrals are introduced, but after induction is learned, so I'm trying to prove this by induction.

**My attempt**

I've only gotten so far as to the premise of the induction step.

$$\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac1i & = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\frac1i + \frac1{k+1} \\ & > \ln(k+1) + \frac1{k+1}
\end{split}$$

And somehow, I need to show that this will be greater than $\ln((k+1)+1) = \ln(k+2)$, however I'm completely stuck here.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\ln(k+2) = \ln((k+1)+1) = \ln\left((k+1)\cdot(1+\frac{1}{k+1})\right) = \ln(k+1) + \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{1+k}\right)
$$
Now knowing that $\ln(x+1) \leq x$ you can deduce that :
$$
\ln(k+2) \leq \ln(k+1) + \frac{1}{k+1}
$$
And therefore conclude your proof.

For the proof of the fact I used, simply consider $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i/i! \geq 1+x \implies x \geq \ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Ah, very nice. The inequality you mention has actually been part of an earlier problem, so I guess they put some thought into this. It also looks like a Bernoulli type thing, so that's nice too.

Comment: @Alec. You can also obtain that inequality from $\ln (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x}(1/y)dy.$ For $x>0$ we have $\ln (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x}(1/y)dy<\int_1^{1+x}(1)dy=x.$ Now for $x=1/(k+1)>0$ we have $\ln (k+2)-\ln (k+1)=\ln (1+x)<x=1/(k+1).$

Comment: One should not use something such as Taylor series to prove that $x \geq \ln(1+x)$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac1i & = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\frac1i + \frac1{k+1} \\ & > \ln(k+1) + \frac1{k+1}
\end{split}

All you need now is to prove that
$$
\frac 1 {k+1} > \ln(k+2)-\ln(k+1).
$$
you have
$$
\ln(k+2)-\ln(k+1) = \int_{k+1}^{k+2} \frac{dx} x <\int_{k+1}^{k+2} \frac {dx} {k+1} = \frac 1 {k+1}.
$$

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this explain what their objection is? $\qquad$

Comment: I would guess it's because you used an integral despite the "Caveat" in the question.

Comment: I would guess the same, though I want to state that I did not downvote it. Since the question has already been answered to my satisfaction, I'm only happy to see alternative solutions afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\ln t$ is the area under the curve $f(x) = \frac 1x$ from $1$ to $t$.

Draw the graph of $f$ and note that: $\ln(n+1) - \ln(n) \le \max\limits_{x \in [n,n+1]}f(x) = f(n) = \frac 1n$